# Node.JS: Cannot connect to Microsoft Azure Database when using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I am trying to connect Azure database using the express + Sequelize. I cannot get connection to work.

I have modified the database.json connection file like this:

```
"development": {
    "username": "XXX",
    "password": "XXX",
    "database": "XXX",
    "host": "XXX",
    "dialect": "mssql",
    "port": 1433,
    "dialectOptions": {
      "encrypt": true
    }
  }
```

I try to connect with sequelizer like this

```
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}
```

I get error message:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHU1o.png

If I directly change Sequelize connection without using the JSON file and connect it like this:

```
sequelize = new Sequelize('XXX', 'XXX', 'XXX', { host: 'XXX', dialect: 'mssql', dialectOptions: { options: { encrypt: true } } });
```

I get error about Username being empty:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFYkQ.png

I have tried connection with MySql and everything works in there. Problems are only when connecting to Azure database. Any help would be great guys! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I connected as below. It works.

```
   const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, username, password, {
  host: config.databaseHost,
  Port: config.databasePort, // 49175 // 1433
  dialect: 'mssql',

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  },
  dialectOptions: {
    instanceName: 'SQLEXPRESS',
    requestTimeout: 60000
  }
});
sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks! Hmm, strange. I still get the 'SequelizeConnectionError: Server requires encryption, set 'encrypt' config option to true.'

Answer (score 0):

Got it working! I didnt have Tedious Installed. Aftet that all is working.